# Robot Framework Integration

Tags: robotframework, hp-quality-center

We have a project which uses Robot Framework 2.7.7, while we are using HP-QC for Bug tracking.

Is it possible to integrate Robot Framework with HP Quality center?

Comment: What do you want the integration to do?

Comment: Well, like QTP is integrated with QC. A test is connected to a bug. When the test is fullfilled the status of the Bug changes at QC.

Comment: If you use Jenkins, there is already a plugin for Robot.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't described much in terms of "integration" but from your message I can understand that what you are looking for a way to open new defects in your QC/ALM defects module.

This can be achieve in multiple ways:

1. [Open Test Architecture API](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/ota/webframe.html) - Open Test Architecture API is a COM library that enables you to integrate external applications with ALM/QC.
2. [REST API](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.20/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html) - You can even create a client application or module based on the API to create, read, update, and delete entities.
3. Interact directly with the MS SQL database - This method is less safer and might be problematic, so I wouldn't recommend it.

I'm sure that there are other ways to do it but this is all I can think of right now...

Answer (score 0):

Integration can be done in multiple ways.

One of the way is to use VAPI. If you are using VBS or Java  VAPI, (visual Application programming Interface) will be useful.  The VAPI integrator can be used for integration with ROBOT. The integrator has capability of launching  third part applications which can be used to launch   ROBOT test suite. The Robot testscript  have capability to save execution result in external file. The VAPI integrator can get inputs from this dynamically updated file as test cases keep on updating results.

At he end it is possible to script to parse Robot result file and update required fields in QC.  I think you are looking for specific case of case tied up with bug. The script will change the  bug related test case status after execution.